# html div not occuping full height of the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to split the screen into two sections so basically 50% width and each section must occupy full height of the browser. But I'm unable to fill the entire height as shown in the picture below it displays white area

So far I have got up to this:

[image: UI]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid  d-flex flex-column">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: green">
      <img src="./images/user2.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
      <h1>STATUS: IN</h1>
      <h1>NAME: MIKE LEE</h1>
      <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: XX/YY/00</h1>
      <h1>CONTRACTOR: SAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
      <h1>GRANTED ACCESS</h1>
      <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: red">
      <img src="./images/default_user_round.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
      <h1>STATUS: OUT</h1>
      <h1>NAME: JOHN DOE</h1>
      <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: EXAMPLE/SAMPLE/00</h1>
      <h1>CONTRACTOR: EXAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
      <h1>DENIED ACCESS</h1>
      <h1>REASON: 60 HOUR VIOLATION DETECTED</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Also if there is only one section it must occupy full height and width of the browser. I'm using rows but it's not mandatory or if there is any other approach do let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi M. Gomes, it looks like your example needs some more styles. You are probably using Twitter Bootstrap. So, could you add the bootstrap specific CSS stylings, please? `row`, `col-sm-6` and so on is missing. You cannot expect us, to be familiar with your tech stack. Twitter Bootstrap is only one CSS frameworks of thousands.

Comment: **@M. Gomes:** You need to define **min-height: 100vh;** in body and *inherit* height of parent element to define in **col-sm-6** class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-fluid {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.full-height{
height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .full-height{
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">s
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    <title>Display</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid  d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 full-height" style="background-color: green">
                <img src="./images/user2.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
                <h1>STATUS: IN</h1>
                <h1>NAME: MIKE LEE</h1>
                <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: XX/YY/00</h1>
                <h1>CONTRACTOR: SAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
                <h1>GRANTED ACCESS</h1>
                <h1></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 full-height" style="background-color: red">
                <img src="./images/default_user_round.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
                <h1>STATUS: OUT</h1>
                <h1>NAME: JOHN DOE</h1>
                <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: EXAMPLE/SAMPLE/00</h1>
                <h1>CONTRACTOR: EXAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
                <h1>DENIED ACCESS</h1>
                <h1>REASON: 60 HOUR VIOLATION DETECTED</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Firstly, I have corrected your `<meta>` rule inside head section. And because we want to make our content responsive to varied displays, I used `vh` values.

You haven't used `.container` so I removed it. Probably you were just testing with it and `container-fluid`.

Next I created separate class `.full-height` for code re-usability and set `height: 100vh;` to its contents, and used it with both columns to make them attain full height of the view-port

Finally, I am sure you not want to hide your contents on small devices. So I have used `overflow-y: scroll;` inside `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`, which ensures scrolling inside div on small devices. If you want to hide it, just replace `overflow-y: scroll;` with `overflow-y: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: green">
      <img src="./images/user2.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
      <h1>STATUS: IN</h1>
      <h1>NAME: MIKE LEE</h1>
      <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: XX/YY/00</h1>
      <h1>CONTRACTOR: SAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
      <h1>GRANTED ACCESS</h1>
      <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: red">
      <img src="./images/default_user_round.png" alt="user" style="height: 256px; width: 256px" />
      <h1>STATUS: OUT</h1>
      <h1>NAME: JOHN DOE</h1>
      <h1>EMPLOYEE ID: EXAMPLE/SAMPLE/00</h1>
      <h1>CONTRACTOR: EXAMPLE PVT. LTD.</h1>
      <h1>DENIED ACCESS</h1>
      <h1>REASON: 60 HOUR VIOLATION DETECTED</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parent container (.row) to be display flex.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

This should do it, and then you can modify the look of them by using css-flex properties [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried it and does it, but if I make it full screen I can again see the white area.